# Operator overloading - dynamic object alocation issue

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, dynamic, operator-overloading

I've got a class QueueSorted which stores a sorted list of objects (of a class Task).

```
QueueSorted q1;

qq1+=t1; // adding object t1 to the list
qq1+=t2;
qq1+=t3;
```

The code above **works**.

This code is not:

```
QueueSorted *q1 = new QueueSorted();

qq1+=t1;
qq1+=t2;
qq1+=t3;
```

+= prototype looks like this:

```
Queue & operator+=(const Task & task);
```

it says "no operator += matches these operands".
How to make it work?

Comment: This has nothing to do with dynamic allocation BTW.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In second case you should use the following forms:

```
qq1->operator+=(t1);
qq1->operator+=(t2);
qq1->operator+=(t3);
```

or

```
(*qq1) += t1;
(*qq1) += t2;
(*qq1) += t3;
```

Comment: Note: The first one is possible but it ignores the philosophy of operators to make the code more readable.

Comment: @MM. Yes, sure. I have written it to highlight that we need to use pointer dereference operator it this case.

Answer (score 1):

You should dereference it by `*` and then use the operator :

```
*qq1 += t1;
```

Otherwise compiler tries to apply `+=` to a pointer-to-QueueSorted which is not applicable.